# Cassandra query timestamp column

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Using Cassandra 2.28, Drive 3, Sparks2. 
I have a timestamp column in Cassandra I n**eed to query it by the date portion only**. If I query by date: `.where("TRAN_DATE= ?", "2012-01-21"` : it does not bring any result. If I include the time portion it says Invalid Date. My data (as I can read in cqlsh) is: 2012-01-21 08:01:00+0000

param: "2012-01-21" > No error but no result

param: "2012-01-21 08:01:00" > **Error : Invalid Date**

param: "2012-01-21 08:01:00+0000" > **Error : Invalid Date**

SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
TRAN_DATE =   DATE_FORMAT.parse("1/19/2012"); 
Have used the bulk loader/SSLoader to load the table

Data in table:

```
tran_date                | id
--------------------------+-------
 2012-01-14 08:01:00+0000 |    ABC
 2012-01-24 08:01:00+0000 |    ABC
 2012-01-23 08:01:00+0000 |    ALM
 2012-01-29 08:01:00+0000 |    ALM
 2012-01-13 08:01:00+0000 |    ATC
 2012-01-15 08:01:00+0000 |    ATI
 2012-01-18 08:01:00+0000 |    FKT
 2012-01-05 08:01:00+0000 |    NYC
 2012-01-11 08:01:00+0000 |    JDU
 2012-01-04 08:01:00+0000 |    LST
```

How do I solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you insert data into timestamp column without providing timezone like this one :

```
INSERT INTO timestamp_test (tran_date , id ) VALUES ('2016-12-19','TMP')
```

Cassandra will choose coordinator timezone

> If no time zone is specified, the time zone of the Cassandra coordinator node handing the write request is used. For accuracy, DataStax recommends specifying the time zone rather than relying on the time zone configured on the Cassandra nodes.

If you execute select with Datastax Driver, you Need To Convert the String date into java.util.Date and set the time zone of coordinator node, In my case it was GMT+6

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("2012-01-21");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6")); //Change this time zone
```

Now You can query with

```
QueryBuilder.eq("TRAN_DATE", date)
```

Here is a complete demo :

```
try (Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("127.0.0.1").withCredentials("username", "password").build(); Session session = cluster.connect("tests")) {
    session.execute("INSERT INTO test_trans(tran_date , id ) VALUES ('2016-12-19','TMP')");

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6"));
    Date date = dateFormat.parse("2016-12-19");
    System.out.println(date);
    for (Row row : session.execute(QueryBuilder.select().from("timestamp_test").where(QueryBuilder.eq("tran_date", date)))) {
        System.out.println(row);
    }
}
```

Source : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html

Comment: Thanks. Yes I need to use Date and not date String - query runs now (no errors). But still I have the same problem - **no results**. Need to solve the time issue.

Comment: Add some more details

Comment: My column is 'timestamp' so my data in table is date-time (Even though the  original data was date only). Now when I try query it by date only the query fails- likely does not match. I tried query with date-time - errors out. (details in the original question). So the problem I need to solve is query by date and get the match. I am OK to query any which way- tried 2 options both did not work. So How

Comment: Couldn't solve the problem yet. This should be a common issue -  there needs to be a solution for this.

Comment: show us your sample data and for which date the result is empty

Comment: Added sample data, timestamp tran_id and 3 char ID. Query .cassandraTable("tests", "test_trans").where("ID= ?", "ABC").where("TRAN_DATE= ?", "2012-01-21  08:01:00");

Comment: @Sam-T Answer Edited

Comment: This problem got solved. My data load was goofed up instead of date format "yyyy-MM-dd"  I had mistakenly set "yyyy-mm-dd" (so Minute instead of Month) - sort if honest/silly mistake. But finally solved (after much frustration).